# Elliptical light source using SVG filters

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to apply a Vignette effect on images with SVG filters. I am trying to implement this with the `<fePointLight>` primitive, but I find this a bit limited in that it is always has a circular shape. Is it possible to change the width such that the lighting effect takes on a wide elliptical shape? This is currently the filter I am using:

```
<filter id="vignette">
    <feFlood id="flood-5" result="blackfield-6" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="1"/>
    <feSpecularLighting id="specular-5" result="Spotlight-6" lighting-color="#FFFFFF" surfaceScale="1" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="100">
        <fePointLight id="pointlight-5" x="720" y="450" z="1200"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feBlend id="svg-7" result="A-6" in="blackfield-6" in2="Spotlight-6" mode="lighten"/>
    <feBlend id="blend-5" result="B-6" in="A-6" in2="SourceGraphic" mode="multiply"/>
</filter>
```

I am aware that it is possible to do this with a radial gradient effect on a separate shape, but I have a requirement that it must be done purely using SVG filters.

Answer (score 2):

The values of the `x=350` and `y=240` attributes of the `fePointLight` filter are chosen so that the point is in the center of the image.
Different values for the `z` attribute of the `fePointLight` filter render the light source at different depths in relation to the drawing. The nearest position corresponds to the largest size.

Please watch in full screen
Hover over image

```css
#img {
width:700px;
height:481px;
}
#img:hover {
filter:url(#spotlight);
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBuDo.jpg" >
      
<svg  width="700" height="481" viewBox="0 0 700 481" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feSpecularLighting result="spotlight" specularConstant="3.5"
          specularExponent="70" lighting-color="grey">
        <fePointLight x="350" y="240" z="520"/>
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="spotlight" operator="in"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
</svg>
```

Other image

```css
#img {
width:700px;
height:481px;
}
#img:hover {
filter:url(#spotlight);
}
```

```html
 <img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlhkD.jpg" >
      
<svg  width="700" height="481" viewBox="0 0 700 481" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feSpecularLighting result="spotlight" specularConstant="3.5"
          specularExponent="70" lighting-color="grey">
        <fePointLight x="350" y="240" z="520"/>
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="spotlight" operator="in"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that sort of effect (elliptical light), you probably want to be using a spotlight rather than a point light.

If you offset the light position to one side and shine the cone down at a shallow-ish angle, you will get an elliptical spot.

```html
<svg width="600" height="529">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feSpecularLighting result="spotlight" specularConstant="1.5"
          specularExponent="4" lighting-color="#FFF">
        <feSpotLight x="-200" y="265" z="400" limitingConeAngle="10" pointsAtX="300" pointsAtY="265" />
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="spotlight" operator="out" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="529" style="fill: skyblue; filter:url(#spotlight);"/>
</svg>
```

Note that the lighting filter components can be unreliable to use. Each browser has differences in interpretation of the standard.  Not to mention some bugs.
A point in case is the above example, which looks different in Firefox and Chrome.

But good luck with your project.

Comment: You can post-process the spotlight with feColorMatrix or feComponentTransfer to even out the lighting. And you can also do inline an ellipse into feImage using data:uris - which  would be the cross browser way to solve this.